# Symfony2 render assets programmatically and to string

Tags: symfony, assetic

How do I render assets through a filter (Closure) within a class, without people from the outside being able to see the file (i.e. not placing the file in the `web` folder). Should be possible as Assetic is able to do it.

I've already looked at the assetic code but I was not able to figure out how to do this.

Comment: So you want to serve assets to the web user, without ever putting the file in the web directory? Think about that

Comment: It's an script that includes an API key. But it has to be served as small as possible. The script will then be rendered through twig and cached. But the original script and the compiled `*.js.twig` script should indeed not be visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kris Wallsmith (maker of assetic) helped me out doing this, and helped me in the right direction.

```
$asset = new FileAsset(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/assets/script.js');
$closureFilter = new CompilerJarFilter(
    $this->getContainer()->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/Resources/java/compiler.jar'
);
$closureFilter->setCompilationLevel(CompilerJarFilter::COMPILE_ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS);
$asset->ensureFilter($closureFilter);
$script = $asset->dump();
```